# Where to get a list of Docker images/tags for .netcore at mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core?

Tags: .net-core

Where can I get a full list of all available tags for the official docker images for .netcore ?

https://mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core => redirecting to some wired azure pages
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core/ => tags menu is gone

Answer (score 12):

I finally found the answer by myself.

You can just open:
https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/dotnet/core/sdk/tags/list in the browser to get all tags ...

Comment: Oh my god... you literally saved me. This is nowhere documented... the official hub.docker.com site publishes dotnet/runtime dotnet/sdk etc but the /core/ part is missing and you can not literally find anywhere the full tags output but by direct hitting this service... Thank you so much!

Comment: For .NET 6, link is https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/dotnet/sdk/tags/list.

Comment: How about a .Net 4.8 windows image? Do they have one in the MCR?